How to access Youtube APIs from server
I'm building a yt summarizer app. So for that I'm using youtube-transcript-api & pytube, to get the transcript, or audio if the first is disabled. Worked fine on my Windows laptop. But on my Apache server running on Ubuntu, linux VM (DigitalOcean droplet), it isn't working at all. It says subtitles are disabled when it actually isn't, HTTP Error 400: Bad Request, "This request has been detected as a bot, please try again or log in to view".
What can I do to make it work?
No api-keys or creds are given in code at the moment, it directly worked locally.

Do not these libraries support providing credentials to an account?

The same is happening to me. I built an app a few months ago and it was working fine. I tried the app today and I am now getting the "detected as a bot" error. A friend of mine mentioned that YouTube has done some recent updates to catch bots from using their API. Seems another solution is needed.
